# Error on Label.toImage().height in android titanium

Tags: android, bitmap, titanium

When I try to get te hight of a label in titanium I get the following error in some Android devices:

```
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [9839,17048] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits; Titanium 5.1.2,2015/12/16 19:00,ca822b2
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:819)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:794)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:761)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiUIHelper.viewToImage(TiUIHelper.java:764)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIView.toImage(TiUIView.java:1718)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleToImage(TiViewProxy.java:935)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:278)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The erro line is as followed:

```
var a1 = mLabel.toImage().height;
```

But this error only course in some devices, not on all android devices.

How can I get the height of the label on all devices wit out that error?

Comment: i think this problem happen in 32 bit devices and not happen in 64 bit. am i right?

Comment: I figured sorting else out. when I set the Height and Width of my babes as 'auto' it gives my that error but when I set it to Ti.UI.SIZE it works how it should. But why does it work with 'auto' in some devices and in other doesn't?